# How to populate collection in Strapi V3?

Tags: javascript, strapi, populate

I'm trying to create custom controller for my Strapi (v3.6.10) model, but have a problem with populating one specific field. Here are my models:

1. Parent model:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "clinic_pages",
  "info": {
    "name": "clinic-page",
  },
  "attributes": {
    "clinic": {
      "model": "clinic"
    },
    ...otherParentModelFields,
  }
}
```

2. Clinic:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "clinics",
  "attributes": {
    ...otherFields,
    "schedule": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": true,
      "component": "clinic.schedule"
    },
  }
}
```

3. Schedule:

```
{
  "collectionName": "components_clinic_schedules",
  "info": {
    "name": "schedule",
  },
  "attributes": {
    "time": {...},
    "day": {...}
  }
}
```

I need to populate only few fields from parent model, including `clinic`. So I'm using this query:
`await strapi.services[MODEL].findOne(ctx.query)` and receiving full schedule data in response:

```
{
  ...otherFieldsOfModel,
  clinic: {
    id: 1,
    ...otherFields,
    schedule: [
      { id: 1, time: '9:00', day: 'monday' },
      { id: 2, time: '10:00', day: 'tuesday' }
    ]
  }
}
```

That's fine, I see clinic and schedule, and all other fields in parent model. But then I wand to add `populate` to reduce size of those other fields and what I got?. Every time I'm getting anything instead of populated data for `clinic.schedule` even if I'm adding it to `populate` list. In all this cases:

```
await strapi.services[MODEL].findOne(ctx.query, {});
await strapi.services[MODEL].findOne(ctx.query, {clinic: true});
await strapi.services[MODEL].findOne(ctx.query, ['clinic']);
await strapi.services[MODEL].findOne(ctx.query, ['clinic', 'clinic.schedule', 'clinic.schedule.day', 'clinic.schedule.time']);
```

and so on... I mean I tried any possible syntax variant and don't even got a `schedule: null`. This field not returning anymore in the response. How do I populate this collection?

P.S. Yes, I know that Strapi is v4 already, unfortunately I can't update it for now.

Comment: What is your exact issue? Are you not able to populate or you are able to populate but you want to populate only few fields?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni Cannot populate deep, starting from level ~3.